# WPF Charting + Grid help

Tags: wpf, grid, wpftoolkit, charts

We I'm looking for good WPF toolkit (ones that cost money) that can provide both powerful grid and charting. I'm not that up-to-date whats out there, so i was hoping anyone can assist me with where i should look for. some of the most needed features we need:

Grid:

- Hierarchical tree grid

Charting:

- panning and  Zooming
- 3D charts
- Empty Data point display
- Line chart / Scatter Plot

any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152016/best-charting-tool-for-silverlight-and-wpf

Answer (score 0):

We're currently using two toolkits for WPF development:

- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx)
- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx#Overview)

They both features charts and a powerful grid, plus a bunch of other things. There isn't much between them to be honest. Telerik seems to look a bit slicker. On the other hand the technical support you get from Infragistics is first class and well worth paying for. You can get a chat session with an actual developer within a couple of minutes and they usually have a solution for whatever problem you are facing.

I would happily recommend either of these.